# setting the output reg of one device to be the input of another device in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

i want the value of the output reg of a module to be used as input of another module .How can I do so ?
the following code shows errors when i try to connect the output of a 3 bit upcounter to a 3to8 decoder

```
module combouno(clk,enb,rest,dec);
input clk,enb,rest;
output reg [7:0]dec;
 wire [2:0]Q;
thrbitup uno(clk,Q,enb,rest);   
egtbtdec dec1(Q,dec);
endmodule
module thrbitup(clkk,q,en,res);
input clkk,en,res;
output reg [2:0]q;
always@(posedge clkk,negedge res)

if(res==0)
q<=0;

else if(en)
q<=q+1;


endmodule

module egtbtdec(x,y);
input [2:0]x;
output reg [7:0]y;

always@(x)
begin
case(x)
3'b000 : y=8'b00000001;
3'b001 : y=8'b00000010;
3'b010 : y=8'b00000100;
3'b011 : y=8'b00001000;
3'b100 : y=8'b00010000;
3'b101 : y=8'b00100000;
3'b110 : y=8'b01000000;
3'b111 : y=8'b10000000;
endcase
end 
endmodule
```

the error is as follows
Error (10663): Verilog HDL Port Connection error at combouno.v(6): output or inout port "y" must be connected to a structural net expression

Answer (score 0):

Your port should only be 'reg' in the place where you assign the values.

Any other ports in the hierarchy which pass this signal do not need to know if the original port was a reg or wire.

Thus remove the reg in the top level module:

```
module combouno(clk,enb,rest,dec);
input clk,enb,rest;
output [7:0]dec;
```

Anyway it is better to switch to the ANSI port style:

```
module combouno
   (
   input clk,enb,rest, 
   output [7:0]dec  
   );
```

Also check for typing errors: you are using 'res' and 'rest'.